# android RelativeLayout view (for data) appears outside map popup (coming from a tap event)

Tags: android, arcgis

Firstly, sorry for poor layout, it's the first time that i am asking a question. i have done searches on this issue, but couldn't find solutions.

Now, for my project, i have to add an identify on a map-object. It works fine, i can get the results i want to obtain. But the problems appears when i want to display the result of the identify task on a view.

I have styled the RelativeLayout in a XML file, here is the snippet. i have removed a large part due of not relevant. The layout contains 4 fields, i am going to display only one of it

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
style="@style/basic"
tools:context=".HelloWorldActivity" >

<com.esri.android.map.MapView
    android:id="@+id/map"
    style="@style/basic"
    initExtent = "-1849.3798815878108 139037.2620862738 219078.1453067956 241431.21687418327">
</com.esri.android.map.MapView>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/objectInfo"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    style="@style/objectInfo" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/labelStatus"
        style="@style/labelProperty"
        android:text="@string/labelStatus" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/status"
        style="@style/textObjectInfo"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/labelStatus"
        android:text="@string/status" />
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now, i am using a custom class, which extends from IdentifyResultSpinnerAdapter. The purpose is to callback with a View-content (Identify is being handled with async task). Here below is the method i'm using to return with a View object;

```
        RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) mainThread.findViewById(R.id.objectInfo);
    // set textview
    TextView txt;

    // set naam
    txt = (TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.status);
    if(curResult.getAttributes().containsKey("status")){
        txt.setText(curResult.getAttributes().get("status").toString());    
    }
    else txt.setText("N/A");
    // **1

    layout.invalidate();
    layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    return layout;
```

( **1 as said, only displaying one change, the other 3 fields are handled the same way)
And then in the main activity class;

```
/**
* this method handles the result after tap event and displays it on the map
* @param p the point where the tap event got recorded
* @param v the view result
* @see IdentifyTaskManager
*/
public void handleResults(Point p, ViewGroup v) {
    mMapView.getCallout().show(p, v);
}
```

The next image shows the result of the above code.
(eh you need 10 rep points for image displaying, [here is the URL](http://imageshack.us/a/img546/4900/temp2u.png)

As you can see, the RelativeLayout window (in orange) is appearing as a static layout staying on that place, no matter which object i'm tapping on the map. The popup window appears as empty because the layout doesn't result there.

Does any1 know what the problem is, or something which can cause this effect ?
thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found the solution. I decided to dig into the View / RelativeLayout documentation and came across LayoutInflater class. Thanks to both links, [this question on stackovervlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9359505/how-to-bind-a-view-to-alertdialog-and-use-the-children-in-this-view-in-android) and [this blog](http://www.jayway.com/2009/03/26/layout-resources-in-android/) i could work out a solution.

Firstly, i moved the xml layout to a separate file, called popupwindow.xml

Secondly, using LayoutInflater class (variable mainThread is a reference to the main class which extends from Activity - required to obtain Context info);

```
View view = null;
try {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mainThread.getBaseContext());
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popupwindow, null); // get info from popupwindow.xml
}
catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d(null, "159 - error after inflater : " + e.getMessage());
}
// return null if inflater fails;
if (view == null) return null;

// set textview
TextView txt;

// set status
txt = (TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.status);
if(curResult.getAttributes().containsKey("status")){
    txt.setText(curResult.getAttributes().get("status").toString());    
}
// return view
return view;
```

me ish happy :-)